# iOS App - Open website in browser choosed by user

Tags: ios, swift, android-intent, webview

I need to develope an app, which redirects a user to our onlineshop.

First I tried it via webview, but the webview introduces some bugs, e.g. I can't open PDF files.

I solved it in android by using `Intent`:

```
package de.example.onlineshop;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class FullscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public void openWebPage(String url)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        openWebPage("https://www.example.com");
        finish();
    }



}
```

This works perfect. The user is asked in which browser he wants to open our website and then the website opens in that app.

Does it also work in iOS, preferably with swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open url in default browser by adding following code,

```
func openWebPage(urlStr: String)
{
   guard let url = URL(string: urlStr) else {
     return //be safe
   }      
   if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
   } else {
       UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default it opens in Safari but if you have other browser as well user will asked to choose a browser -

```
guard let url = URL(string: "some url") else {
return
}
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
   UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```